# pandas: groupby using a generic key function acting on one of more columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I browsed for a while but could not find a way to group a pandas data frame using a function.

For example, assume:

```
df2=df1.groupby(df1['ColA']).sum()
```

Can we define a function *f* such that:

```
df2=df1.groupby(f).sum()
```

Can this function *f* also take inputs from several columns of *df1*? For example, what if the key according to which the grouping is done is a function of df['ColA'] and df['ColC']? I cannot find any example on this although it seems it should be possible from the API doc at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html.

Thanks

Comment: It says list of column names, e.g. ``df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()`` will work, docs are here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once (look down a couple of sections to see an example of this)

Comment: If you provide a function like `df1.groupby(f)`, then this will be applied to each element fo the index to determine the grouping, so this is not what you want. But can't you do `df1.groupby(f(df1['ColA'], df1['ColC']))`?

Comment: well, I saw this but I was hoping to give a generic function as input, e.g. key1 is defined by f(df['A'], df['B']), key2 is defined by  g(df['C'], df['D']), then  I can obtain df1 = df.groupby(f) and df2=df.groupby(g), where g and f are defined somewhere else. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could apply `f` first, and pass the return value to `groupby`:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(f(df['ColA'], df['ColB'])).sum()
```

Note that you can pass a list of arrays to `groupby`.
So, if you have two functions and want to use both return values as keys, you could do this:

```
df2 = df1.groupby([f(df['ColA'], df['ColB']),
                   g(df['ColC'], df['ColD'])]).sum()
```